# Show query tables even without data

Tags: mysql

I have a query, but every time I run it, it will only show the item, show, etc, etc that has all of the info.

SELECT DISTINCTROW tblEvents.EventID, [ShowName] & " " & Format([StartDate],"mm-yyyy") AS ShowNames, tblShowTypes.ShowType, tblStates.StateCode, Format([StartDate],"dd-mmm-yyyy") AS Start, Format([EndDate],"dd-mmm-yyyy") AS [End], tblInsideOutside.InsideOutside, tblHomeAway.HomeAway, tblShowCosts.BoothCost, tblComments.Comment
FROM ((((((tblEvents INNER JOIN tblShows ON tblEvents.ShowID = tblShows.ShowID) INNER JOIN tblShowTypes ON tblShows.ShowTypeID = tblShowTypes.ShowTypeID) INNER JOIN tblStates ON tblEvents.StateID = tblStates.StateID) INNER JOIN tblInsideOutside ON tblShows.InsideOutsideID = tblInsideOutside.InsideOutsideID) INNER JOIN tblShowCosts ON tblEvents.EventID = tblShowCosts.EventID) INNER JOIN tblHomeAway ON tblShows.HomeAwayID = tblHomeAway.HomeAwayID) INNER JOIN tblComments ON tblShowCosts.EventID = tblComments.EventID;

Comment: Don't be shy.  Put the query in your question.

Comment: Please provide table definitions.

Comment: You said you have a query, please post that query.

Comment: @JoshuaG `SELECT a.foo, b.bar FROM atable a INNER JOIN btable b ON b.a_id=a.id`.

Comment: @JoshuaG  Was responding on how to post a query.  I've since see you have.  I am not an expert like many on this forum, however, your query seems to have some flaws.  All the parentheses for one, however, I don't think they are doing anything.  Also, never used the square brackets (i.e. `[ShowName]`) like you have.  If you are not getting results, it is probably because you are doing an inner join which must match, and maybe you should use an outer join.

Comment: I changed the INNER JOIN to LEFT OUTER JOIN and it errors saying, and I quote :)     "JOIN expression not supported"                                                                              @User1032532, I did not write any of that, that is just the SQL code I got after using the query wizard.

Comment: I recommend trying a few simple joins and get some results.  Don't worry about selecting all the columns at first, and maybe even use the cursed `*`.  Add a table at a time until you understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others said, please show your query.  That being said, change from `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.  Again, can't be sure without knowing your schema.

Comment: Thanks! Worked just fine! I would +1, but I think I have a negative rep :/

Comment: Yikes!  Negative reps.  That's no good!  Spend some time understanding JOINs.  They are one of the most important things to understand.  A good book is Simple SQL, and you might want to consider reading it or some other.

Comment: Thanks man! This is very, very helpful, I should probably end up reading that book some time, and, thanks to you, understand some more of the SQL :) Thanks once again!